# Struts2 form-fields validation does not work

Tags: java, validation, configuration, struts2, struts-validation

I'm trying to implement the validation as described [here](http://struts.apache.org/docs/validation.html#Validation-DefiningValidationRules) (struts2 documentation). My Class :

```java
public class FatturaAction extends BaseAction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6586322371651933659L;
    private FatturaForm fatturaForm;

    //getter and setter
}
```

The `FatturaForm`:

```java
public class FatturaForm {

    private Date data;

    //getter and setter
}
```

My XML (FatturaAction-validaton.xml):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0//EN"
          "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.dtd">
<validators>
    <field name="fatturaForm.data"> 
        <field-validator type="required"> 
            <message>You cannot leave the email address field empty.</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

The validation is not hit, even if the field is empty. I'm using `<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />` so the validation interceptor is activated.

**EDIT:**

I also tried the `non field validator`:

```
<validators>
    <validator type="required"> 
        <param name="fieldName">data</param> 
        <message>You must enter a value for bar.</message> 
    </validator>
</validators>
```

It doesn't hit either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a wrong DTD:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0//EN" 
          "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.dtd">
```

the right one for latest version of Struts 2 is

```xml
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
          "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
```

Also ensure your **FatturaAction-validaton.xml** is in the **action** folder, NOT in the **bean** folder (that's right only for *Visitor* Validation)

Comment: Did it work @Emaborsa ?

Comment: Sorry i didn't try yet... I let you know. What is your opinion to @Romans statement? Do you agree with him?

Comment: No, he simply confused the action with the bean.

Comment: Yes it works. Now I'll implement all validations, I'll let you know. Thanks!